# Isolation level not working in spring boot

Tags: database, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, transactions

Recently I started working with isolation levels, but specifying isolation level in `@Transactional` annotation does not seems to work in spring boot. I tried a lot of different things but I cannot get it to work, below is my code.

```
@Transactional(isolation=Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
 public  void updateWalletAddresses(List<RegisterWallet>      walletMetaCollection) throws Exception{
    Transaction tx =null;
    Session session =null;
    if(sessionFactory == null){
        return;
    }   
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();     
    try{
       String sql = "select * from user";   

       SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
       query.addEntity(User.class);
       List<User> userlist=query.list();
       int i=0;
       while(i<userlist.size()){
        System.out.println(userlist.get(i).getEmail());
        i++;
    }

    }catch(Exception e){

        throw e;
    }
}
```

before executing the above walletservice method I am starting a transaction 
in mysql client but I am not committing it so that I have dirty data.
After that I executed above code but it does not print uncommitted data even though I specified transaction read uncommitted.
code for starting transaction in mysql is

```
set autocommit=0;
start transaction;
insert into user (name,email,password,roleid,username) 
values("prashank","myemail@gmail.com","password",1,"prashank");
```

Note: as I am not committing the transaction then above insert cause dirty read problem. I am not able to read uncommitted data 
Note: Similarly any other isolation level are not working .
Please help

Comment: Are you sure that transactions are properly enabled in your app?  Per [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations): `the mere presence of the @Transactional annotation is not enough to activate the transactional behavior. The @Transactional annotation is simply metadata that can be consumed by some runtime infrastructure that is @Transactional-aware and that can use the metadata to configure the appropriate beans with transactional behavior.`

Comment: yes transactions are enabled spring boot will auto enable them

Comment: I still cross checked whether transaction are enabled or not by inserting a user in and then manually throwing an exception. Inserted User is rolled back successfully. i.e transaction is working

Comment: Any link for changing isolation level in "Spring-Boot" will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What's calling this code?  Is it possible the calling code has a different isolation level with propagation such that it will be enlisting in an existing transaction that uses read_committed?  See:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086567/isolation-level-read-uncommitted-not-working

Comment: hey,  this was the issue i was calling the it from separate transaction and in that transaction isolation level was repeatable read. issue solved thanx brother :-).

Comment: You should also not be doing `openSession`  but use `currentSession` instead. When opening a new session you might even get a new transaction, rendering the `@Transactional` useless. (With `openSession` you are opening a new session outside the scope of spring, you aren't closing it so you are also leaking connections).

Comment: Yes agree with session leak problem but by default i.e if do not create transaction  through session.beginTransaction() , session work in non-transnational way.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your DB engine with

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'table_name';
```

If is MyISAM, then transactional is not supported, 
use below to create InnoDB, which support transaction, then your case should work

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect
```

Also I don't think

```
set autocommit=0;
```

is required bcz start transaction will automatically disable it